# Creating a double nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

So I have three tables and the structure that I want to create is:

```
{
   'Id'
   'Name'
   'ImagePath'
   'SubCategory':[{

              'Id'
              'Name'
              'ImagePath'
              'Dishes': [{

                      'Id'
                      'Name'
                      'ImagePath'
               }, More Dish Objects]
   }, More SubCategory Objects ]

}
```

I'm querying this data from a MySQL Database and so far I think I've got the query right:

```
Select subcategory.*, dishes.*, category.* from category 
LEFT JOIN subcategory on subcategory.cat_id = category.id 
LEFT JOIN dishes on dishes.subcat_id = subcategory.id;
```

Now I just can't wrap my head around how to structure this using JavaScript.

Comment: What are you using to compose the json?   C#, Java,... ?

Comment: I'm using Javascript through NodeJS.

Comment: and what´s the problem?

Comment: I'd guess, telling by the SQL query, that he has a got a huge table from mysql with lots of duplicate values due to the joins, and doesn't know how to convert that into a tree structure.

Comment: Yes, I want to convert it into the JSON structure that I've written down. I can handle the duplicate columns by renaming them, what I don't understand is how to loop through the result set and generate the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would create a JSON object matching the one you gave in javascript

```
var myJSON ={
    'Id':'sampleId',
    'Name':'sampleName',
    'ImagePath':'sampleImagePath',
    'SubCategory':{
        'Id':'subCategoryId',
        'Name':'subCategoryName',
        'ImagePath':'subCategoryImagePath',
        'Dishes':{
            'Id':'dishesId',
            'Name':'dishesName',
            'ImagePath':'dishesImagePath'
        }
    'AnotherSubCategoryObject':'data'
    }
}

//calling ImagePath in javascript. Value is sampleImagePath
var imagePathValue=myJSON.ImagePath;

//calling subCategoryImagePath. Value is subCategoryImagePath
var subCategoryImagePath = myJSON.SubCategory.ImagePath;

//calling Dishes Name. Value is dishesName
var dishesName = myJSON.SubCategory.Dishes.Name;

//assinging values to subCategoryName

myJSON.SubCategory.Name='anotherValue';
```

Comment: The data in this structure is static, what I want is to loop through the result set and end with this structure.

Comment: What is the format of the returned results? How are you getting them in to your javascript program? Are you using the mySQL module from npm?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the mySQL module. I've got different API routes, I want to return this object on a particular route. A sample route:
router.route('/category/Complex/:id')
 .get((req, res) => {    var query = connection.query('Select * from category where Res_id = ?' ...
And then I return the rows through res.jsonp(rows)

Comment: Usually it the mySQL module returns the data in JSON format. If you give me an example of that format that it is returning I think I can help.